# Query mysql complex

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

i want to ask something about query..
I have a mysql table and want to generate a little complex table..

lets say i have these 3 table..

Ship_terms

```
id |  Name        | Keterangan
-------------------------
1  | Installation | Instalasi
2  | Delivery     | Pengiriman
```

Shipp_list

```
id | tipeShipp | namaShipp | Keterangan
----------------------------------------
1  | 1         | KMA       | Bla Bla Bla
2  | 1         | MTECH     | Bla Bla Bla
3  | 2         | JNE       | Bli Bli BLi
```

Shipp_price

```
id | idShipp | kota    | price
_______________________________
1  | 1       | Jakarta | 0
2  | 2       | Jakarta | 0
3  | 3       | Bandung | 10000
4  | 3       | Jakarta | 5000
```

**NOTES :** ship_terms.id = shipp_list.tipeShipp , shipp_price.idShipp = shipp_list.id

and what i exactly want is..
the result of the query (using 'kota = jakarta') is like this...

```
-----------------
INSTALLATION
-----------------
1. KMA - 0
2. MTECH - 0
-----------------
DELIVERY
-----------------
1. JNE - 5000
```

Anybody here can help me??
Thanks

***UPDATE**

here is my query :

```
{
    /* Jika tersedia, lakukan pengambilan data */

    /* Hitung berat */
    $queryBerat = "SELECT SUM(berat)as berat FROM tmp_detail_jual WHERE username = '$_SESSION[uname]'";
    $run = $db->query($queryBerat);
    $data_berat = $run->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $berat = $data_berat[berat]*$data_berat[jumBarang];
    $beratTot = ceil($berat);
    /* ambil data shipping */
     while($data_table = $cek->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
         $idShipp = $data_table[idShipp];
         $harga = $data_table[price];
         /* ambil nama kurir */
         $querynama = "SELECT * FROM shipp_list where id='$idShipp'";
         $getNama = $db->query($querynama);
         while($namaShipp = $getNama->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
             $nama = $namaShipp[namaShipp];
             $keterangan = $namaShipp[keterangan];
             $tipeShipp = $namaShipp[tipeShipp];
             $idShippList = $namaShipp[id];
             /* Cek tipe kurir */
             $queryjenis = "SELECT * FROM ship_terms where id='$tipeShipp'";
             $getJenis = $db->query($queryjenis);
             while($namaTerms = $getJenis->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                 $namaTerm = $namaTerms[name];
                 $keterangan = $namaTerms[keterangan];

                 /* Echo datanya */
                  echo '<br>'.$namaTerm.'<br>';
                  echo $nama.' - '.$harga*$beratTot;



             }
         }
     }
}
```

But i got a result like this

```
-----------------
INSTALLATION
-----------------
KMA - 0
-----------------
INSTALLATION
-----------------
MTECH - 0
-----------------
DELIVERY
-----------------
JNE - 5000
```

can you give a suggest so my query result will be like this

```
-----------------
INSTALLATION
-----------------
1. KMA - 0
2. MTECH - 0
-----------------
DELIVERY
-----------------
1. JNE - 5000
```

Comment: that doesn't seem like English...?

Answer (score 0):

Try for the installation,

```
SELECT namaShipp, price
FROM Shipp_list
INNER JOIN Shipp_price ON shipp_list.id = shipp_price.idShipp
WHERE kota = 'jakarta' AND tipeShipp = 1
```

`AND` for the delivery

```
SELECT namaShipp, price
FROM Shipp_list
INNER JOIN Shipp_price ON shipp_list.id = shipp_price.idShipp
WHERE kota = 'jakarta' AND tipeShipp = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT sl.id,  st.name, sl.namaShipp, sp.price 
FROM Shipp_list sl 
INNER JOIN Ship_terms st ON sl.tipeShipp = st.id 
LEFT JOIN Shipp_price sp ON sl.id = sp.idShipp
```